# Simple calculation

Tags: c#, math

In Excel I have a simple calculation:

```
total = £103000  
percent: 2.14%  
charges = £2,199.05 - Excel formula (total*percent)/100
```

In C# I can't get this to calculate correctly:

```
double percent = 2.14;
double total = 103000;
double charges = (total * percent) / 100;
```

returns **£2,204.20**

I'm sure there is some rounding going on somewhere which is making the calculation incorrect.

I wouldnt expect the spreadsheet to be incorrect, as it was provided by a financial advisor/expert!

I've uploaded a version of the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Alp-JjrjGS3EdDNWbGM5SmN5VWlFb0llVXJORGhfZ0E&usp=sharing):

See Page/Tab 2 for the calculations, cell K20 is where to charges appear

Comment: What is the "expected" result? Also, see the [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) (or a specialized fixed precision) type for math on currency.

Comment: Well, the maths say that your C# program does it correctly. Are you sure you don't have a typo in your spreadsheet?

Comment: Is your percent value in Excel exactly 2.14% or is that just what you see when it's rounded to two decimal places?

Comment: My version of Excel seems to agree with C#. Are you sure the formula in Excel is correct.

Comment: [Google says it's 2204.20](https://www.google.com/search?q=103000+*+.0214)

Comment: -1, not a programming question actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the algebra and the real value is 2.135%.

Examining the spreadsheet provided via Google Docs confirms that the actual percentage is 2.135%. 2.14% is displayed due to format settings.

Comment: It's the value he needs to finish the algorithm and is the solution to his problem.

Comment: In other words, the stored value in Excel is 2.135%, but it appears as 2.14% due to formatting. Likely the person asking the question copied to 2.14% value from the display to the C# program.

Comment: @mbeckish: There should be a fuller explanation, but this is the only answer so far to identify the problem.

Comment: And I'd suspect the same Eric, but we can't know unless kb gives us more information. So I didn't want to overspeculate. Perhaps I should have said that I thought that? I appreciate you stating the potentials .

Comment: OH SNAP i totally overlooked the spreadsheet *facepalm* thanks Eric!

Comment: thanks guys, that's correct, the actual value is 2.135, but displayed as 2.14

Answer (score 0):

You should double-check your Excel values and formula because it is giving you the wrong results.  Floats or not, it shoudln't be off that much on those numbers in that calculation.

Comment: This answer touches on the points in the comments for this question. I see no reason to down vote this.

Answer (score -1):

You could change it to a float for more accuracy if required, but according to my calc.exe 2,204.20 is spot on.

Comment: in C#, float is a single precision (32 bit) number.  double is a double precision (64 bit) number.

Comment: `decimal percent = new decimal(2.14);
decimal total = 103000;
decimal charges = (total * percent) / 100;`
//charges still equals 2204.2

Comment: Single-precision float should be adequate for this particular calculation, but it's not too far from its 24-bit (~ 7 decimal digits) accuracy.

Answer (score -1):

This is likely because Excel uses 32-bit floats for their calculations.

The answer you received in C# is correct.

If you want the Excel answer to match, you need to change the data type of the cell you are looking at.

Comment: 32 bit float
1.175494351 E – 38
3.402823466 E + 38

Something tells me you are not right about that first part.

Comment: I said likely, not "this is why".  I'm not an Excel expert :)

Comment: I can understand that, but the range is too large to really have floating point precision problems with this simple of arithmetic. I'm not saying it wasn't a good attempt but it doesn't match the range of the  float 32 type.